# "Пошли домой!" или "Пойдём домой!"?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Как правильнее и литературнее сказать: "Пошли домой!" или "Пойдём домой!"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это смотря кому идти или кого послать.
Если домой пойдут я и ты, то **пойдем**. Если я и вы/Вы - **пойдемте**. Если ты - пойди. Если вы/Вы - **пойдите**. А вот если они, то может быть и **пошлите [их] домой**. 
Правда это уже повелительное наклонение не от **идти**, а от **послать**.
Хотя это смотря куда послали. )))

Answer (score 2):

Тут надо добавить, думаю позволено будет через три года, что "пошли" здесь совсем не повелительное от "послать", а омонимичное ему прошедшее от "пойти". Использование такого прошедшего в качестве императива, приказа, т.е.  повелительного наклонения - вполне нормальное дело. "Первый пошел!" Да, разговорное, но вполне этикетное, никак не пошлое.

Comment: "поехали" - туда же

Answer (score 1):

Правильно в повелительном наклонении - пойдем(те). Пошли(те) - просторечие. Это форма повелительного наклонения глагола послать (пошли письмо)

Comment: а "поехали" - тоже просторечие? если да - пруф? если нет - почему разница?

Answer (score 0):

Кажется, "пошли" в значении "давай пойдём" - разговорное.

"Пошли" - неоднозначно. Оно может значить:

1. глагол "пойти" - изъявительное наклонение, прошедшее время, совершенный вид, первое/второе/третье лицо, множественное число ("сделали пойти"*),
2. глагол "послать" - повелительное наклонение, совершенный вид, второе лицо, единственное число ("сделай послать"*),
3. глагол "пошлить"  - повелительное наклонение, несовершенный вид, второе лицо, единственное число ("делай пошли́ть"*)

- какое многообразие значений!

Если смотреть на формы, то значению

4. глагол "пойти" - побудительное наклонение, совершенный вид, первое лицо, множественное число ("сделаем пойти"*)

- соответствует форма "пойдём".

Причём "пойдём", в свою очередь, - тоже неоднозначно: оно может значить

1. как глагол "пойти" - побудительное наклонение, совершенный вид, первое лицо, множественное число ("давай пойдём"),
2. так и глагол "пойти" - изъявительное наклонение, будущее время, совершенный вид, первое лицо, множественное число ("думаю что пойдём").

Причём форма изъявительного наклонения прошедшего времени совершенного вида множественного числа используется в значении побудительного наклонения не только с глаголом "пойти" - "пошли". Напр.: "побежать" - "побежали!", "поехать" - "поехали!", "погнать" - "погнали!", "почапать" - "почапали" - и т. п., целый список со значением движения. Возможно, и другие примеры есть, но мне в голову что-то не приходят.

Мысли вслух: странно: хотя "пошли" - та же форма что и "поехали", но почему-то к "пошли" у людей претензии, а к "поехали" и пр. - нет. Видимо, из-за послать/пошлить?

*Так не говорят, конечно, но позволяет наглядно представить форму.

Comment: *"сделали пойти"* - вы уверены, что это русский язык? А вообще очень странное у вас деление по значением. Реально у "пошли" всего два грамматических: прошедшее от "пойти" и повелительное от "послать". Первое, правда семантически тоже может использоваться как повелительное наклонение. Но все равно только три значения максимум. Откуда вы столько наворотили?!

Comment: @behemothus 1. разумеется "сделали пойти" - так не говорят. но вы можете предложить лучший способ как наглядно двумя словами выразить следующие 14: "глагол пойти в изъявительном наклонении, прошедшее время, совершенный вид, первое/второе/третье лицо, множественное число"? или это "плохое разрушим, а хорошего строить не умеем"? 2. вы отрицаете что глагол пошлить в повелительном наклонении, несовершенный вид, второе лицо, единственное число имеет форму "пошли". вы уверены что вы знаете русский? как тогда по-вашему выглядит эта форма?

Comment: @behemothus вдобавок, объясните к чему это ваше "столько наворотили"? пишете так, словно я с десяток значений придумал. сами же перечислили 3, а я - 4 - всего одним больше. и где эти "столько" которые я "наворотил"? причём четвёртое (пошли́ть) - совершенно справедливо, не знаю почему вы его отрицаете. может вы пуританин и даже само существование пошлых слов вам тяжело признать?;)

Comment: @behemothus вдобавок, добавил сноску что "сделали пойти" итп - так не говорят